# Try to modify the XML attribute value using XSLT. If there is similar type of elements

Tags: xml, xslt

In XML if there is similar type of elements present and I want to modify the one of the elements attribute value using XSLT.

These is the problem

```
<caption>
  <captionStrings>
    <add name="lion" providerName="xyx"/>
    <add name="tiger" providerName="yxy"/>
    <add name="dog" providerName="yxy"/>
  </captionStrings>
</caption>
```

The expected result will be

```
<caption>
  <captionStrings>
    <add name="lion" providerName="xyx"/>
    <add name="cat" providerName="yxy"/>
    <add name="dog" providerName="yxy"/>
  </captionStrings>
</caption>
```

And I try these approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="caption/captionStrings/add/@name">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">cat</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

please help me with these

Comment: Your attempt cannot work because the `name` attribute is not a child of the `captionStrings` element. Please edit your question and clarify **which** of the attributes you want to modify and show the expected result.

Comment: You have a lion and a tiger. Why only tiger becomes cat?

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear how to determine which attribute should be modified. Perhaps you are looking for:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name[.='tiger']">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">cat</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or maybe it needs to be:

```
<xsl:template match="add[2]/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">cat</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't think there are any other options that would produce the result you show (at least not reasonable ones).

Comment: Is there any approach using {if} statement? I don't want to modify the attribute by using index format

Comment: .......Why not?

Comment: If there are 100 of  similar types of elements  then it will be  difficult to modify the attribute value using index format

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. I suggest again you edit your question and explain, in simple terms, what is the logic that needs to be implemented here.